# Espresso test failure on CircleCI

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, circleci

I'm trying to run Android project instrumentation tests on CircleCI. They execute fine on a local machine, both from Android Studio and command line. CircleCI execution generates this stacktrace for every test:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have window focus and not be requesting layout for over 10 seconds. If you specified a non default root matcher, it may be picking a root that never takes focus. Otherwise, something is seriously wrong. Selected Root:
Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@677cf28, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@677cf28, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#100 ty=1 fl=#81810100 wanim=0x1030466 surfaceInsets=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=800, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}}
. All Roots:
Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@677cf28, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@677cf28, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#100 ty=1 fl=#81810100 wanim=0x1030466 surfaceInsets=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=800, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}}
at android.support.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.get(RootViewPicker.java:99)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule.provideRootView(ViewInteractionModule.java:69)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:23)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:9)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.ViewFinderImpl.getView(ViewFinderImpl.java:68)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:120)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Any suggestions?
Here are relevant parts of circle.yml:

```
machine:
  environment:
    ANDROID_HOME: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux
    ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT: 8

dependencies:
  override:
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter tools,platform-tools,build-tools-21.1.2,android-22,extra-google-m2repository,extra-google-google_play_services,extra-android-support
    - ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux ./gradlew dependencies

test:
  override:
    - emulator -avd circleci-android22 -no-audio -no-window:
        background: true
        parallel: true
    - circle-android wait-for-boot
    # Build everything first
    - ./gradlew assembleDebugAndroidTest
    # Remove the look screen
    - adb shell input keyevent 82
    - sleep 5
    - ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
    # copy the build outputs to artifacts
    - cp -r my-project/build/outputs $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS
    # copy the test results to the test results directory.
    - cp -r my-project/build/outputs/androidTest-results/* $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS
    - (./gradlew assemble):
        timeout: 360
```

Comment: sounds like your app is never ran. Could you get your expresso tests to take screenshots to see what is happening when circleci runs it?

Comment: Did you managed to find a solution ? I have similar problem.

Comment: @Ivelius No solution yet, please post if you find something!

Answer (score 9):

I have contacted CircleCI support and asked them kindly to create an example project with espresso tests.

So [here it is](https://github.com/circleci/EspressoSample).

It helped me. Hope it will help you as well .